# Is the grammar for this verse correct?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, poesía

Is the grammar in the following verse correct? For example is Niña de Amerilla how you'd say "girl in yellow", as in yellow clothing. I'm especially concerned about the second line, starting with Aleteo, which is supposed to say something like: "Shabby coat flapping in the wind."

```
El Niño de Negro (The boy in black (i.e., black clothing) )

Yo miro allá 
y veo el niño de negro.

Aleteo abrigo en mal 
estado por el viento.

Puse mi mano 
hacia un vidrio.

Y darse cuenta de que 
el niño de negro es mi.
```

*EDIT*

Intended meaning:

I look yonder and see the boy in black.

Yo miro (I look)

allá (yonder)

y veo (and I see)

el niño de negro. (the boy in black)

Shabby coat flapping in the wind. (the most sketchy line)

Aleteo(?) ('it' is flapping)

abrigo en mal (shabby coat)

estado por el viento. ('it' is in the wind)

I put forth my hand and touch the glass.

Puse mi mano (I put forth my hand)

hacia un vidrio. (to the glass)

And realize the boy in black is me.

Y darse cuenta de que (and realize)

el niño de negro es mi. (the boy in black is me)

Comment: I would say that there are mistakes in every verse. It wouldn't be difficult to just correct your poem. It would take a just a little bit more to correct it and explain why the changes. But in order to make that effort useful for other future users of this site, maybe you should ask multiple questions for each verse/paragraph (eg. "Is *aleteo* the correct verb tense here?", "how do i conjugate "dar" for "realize that" in this sentence? "is 'es mi' a proper translation for 'is me'?")

Comment: I will add comments to each line.

Comment: @AaronF It is not just a question of adding comments to each line. As Diego says, you would need to ask separate questions for each line. Otherwise, you are asking for a full translation, which is outside the scope for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi humilde opinión (In my humble opinion)

Miro a lo lejos         (I look yonder) 
y veo al niño de negro. (and see the boy in black.)

Abrigo en mal estado  (Shabby coat) "Lamentable abrigo"
ondeando al viento.   (flapping in the wind)

Extendí mi mano        (I put forth my hand)
hacia el vidrio.       (and touch the glass.)

Y me di cuenta que     (And realize)
el niño de negro soy yo. (the boy in black is me)